# How do I fix integer to pointer conversion warning?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int n, b, i, j;
    char *thousand;
    //char a;

    char symbol [] = {'I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M'};

    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 10000: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if( n >= 1000)
    {
        b = n / 1000;
        for(i = 0; i < b; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                thousand = symbol [6];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s",thousand);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'; take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: `thousand = symbol [6];` is an error of incompatible types as explained in the error message.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: Taking a step back: What is this program even supposed to do? You want to repeatedly reassign `symbol[6]` (always `'M'`) to the same variable? And when your loops are exhausted you want to print this value? Were you trying to construct a string with the characters from the array? This looks the like the vague basis for a Roman numeral encoder - minus the encoder.  This is why actually describing your problem, and not just dumping an error message, helps significantly to improve the answers you will receive. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `thousand` is declared as:

```
char *thousand;
```

And in this line:

```
thousand = symbol [6];
```

`thousand`, which is a `char *` is assigned from `symbol[6]`, which
is declared as:

```
char symbol []
```

Thus the error:

```
...conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'...
```

as `symbol[6]` is a `char`, not a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

`thousand` is `char *`. `symbol[6]` is `char`. Thus the error message

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'

You should change `char *thousand` to `char thousand` or `thousand = symbol [6];` to `thousand = symbol + 6` depending on what you want. Probably the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here you declared thousand as character pointer , which means it can store address of a character variable not a character itself. But you are trying to assign a character in thousand. Always remember that pointer stores address.